# Transposing Data from one spreasheet file to another

Tags: database, dataframe, google-sheets, transpose, data-cleaning

It is my 1s time accessing this forum to ask for help, so excuse in advance for any rookie mistake.

Context: I am creating a database of prospecting contacts to implement a B2B Sales Strategy for a Bespoke Software Dev. Company. I started to build this database manually as an MVP, but soon perceived opportunities to optimize it gathering data with the help from prospecting platforms (such as Apollo).

My challenge: I want to transpose specific data from the 1st 7 columns columns from spreadsheet file A (1st image, yellow fields) to spreadsheet file B (2nd image) based on a query that uses the name of the company in file 2 as a querying criteria and returns data from the 7 yellow columns

[File A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibn10.png)

[File B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kphni.png)

**Important Notes:**
A) When querying from file B 'company' there might be more than 1 contact per company. In this case, the query should either i) return the 1st name, ii) return an error message OR iii) create an additional field at file B to insert information on another contact (more complex)

B) When querying from file B 'company' the column rows in file B might be already filled with previous information from other contacts. In this case, the query should either i) return an error message OR ii) create an additional field at file B to insert information on another contact (more complex) without overwriting previous information

C) It would be great to be able to perform there operations using spreasheets. In case it is not possible, other alternatives would be welcome.

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** I am sharing below the link of the spreadsheets:
File B - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YuOHzwIjhWUGGK6tO-Kx-r-HqGBX_WUhyeHvK121Hms/edit#gid=1966093157

Also added desired output as a sheet here

File A - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WXZWauTn91rits3d9a7ioPrOGFGJ8wwBtfevwFUbFPo/edit#gid=109937038

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: also File A = File B

Comment: @player0 updated the files and shared the spreadsheets with the desired output (file b)
would appreciate your help! thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

for importing email addresses from File A to File B try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:B),,9^9)), {FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("1WXZWauTn91rits3d9a7ioPrOGFGJ8wwBtfevwFUbFPo", "apollo-contacts-export (1)!A2:B")),,9^9)), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1WXZWauTn91rits3d9a7ioPrOGFGJ8wwBtfevwFUbFPo", "apollo-contacts-export (1)!F2:F")}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

### [demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C7p7aOEhmSgKvJcGVh_wpa18zHKK54OAFaND7Pbbw-s/edit#gid=1966093157)

Comment: Hi @player0, when I pasted this formula I received a ref error message saying that "array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data", would you know how to fix it? Also, I want that not only email but all the other column with filled information are returned for each company searched. In case there is already an existing company in file B, new rows should be created according to the company count in file B. For instance, for Company 'Nubank', 9 additional rows should be created and their info filled with info from the yellow columns

Comment: Trying to illustrate the process flow here:
1-Search file A company 'nubank'
2a)-If in file B information on a nubank contact is already filled, create new additional rows based on the number of 'nubank' in file A
2b) If in file B information on 'nubank' is not filled, fill with information from yellow columns on file A. Company name can overwrite
3-tranpose yellow columns (First Name Last Name Title Company Person Linkedin Url Email Website) from file A to file B, filling 9 rows that were created
4-Repeat this process for other companies

Comment: @LeonardoCorreia see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C7p7aOEhmSgKvJcGVh_wpa18zHKK54OAFaND7Pbbw-s/edit#gid=1459091810

Comment: Hi @player0, the formula shared seems to be only returning part of the results. Only 4 results are being returned (1 was already filled) when 9 should be possible (see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WXZWauTn91rits3d9a7ioPrOGFGJ8wwBtfevwFUbFPo/edit#gid=109937038  column D, row 'apollo-contacts')

Also, is it possible to return the range already sorted (all 'nubank' contacts are returned, then all 'company b' contacts are returned). Thx